# updating my app to only support iOS 4.3+, what happens to users running iOS < 4.3?

Tags: ios

This seems like a question that should have a lot of answers on Google, but I can not find an answer to this....

I am updating my app to only support iOS 4.3 or later. What happens to users that currently have my app installed and are using  iOS < 4.3. Does the app remain installed on their devices and they are just not eligible for updates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They will not be able to update the app, I believe there will then be a permanent "1" on the AppStore icon. If the user downloads the update in their desktop iTunes, it will overwrite the old version and they'll never be able to install that version on their devices.

As long as they don't restore their iOS (wipe the phone) the app will remain.

EDIT:

There is no reason now to support "4.3+". Any device that canrun 4.3+ can run 5.0+, and any device that can run 5.0+ can run 6.0+.

Staying under 4.3 for iPhone 3G is fine, but if you now support 4.3+ you've really gained nothing other than alienating iPhone 3G users for no benefit.

In other words, users who are still on 4.3 are probably not the type of users who are updating apps from the App Store anyway.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. The reason I choose 4.3, is because this is the minimum iOS version supported in xCode 4.5+ (with the removal of the armv6 architecture). Also, "any device that can run 5.0+ can run 6.0+" is not true in the case of iPad (1st gen). I can see your point about not really gaining anything, but i am feeling forced to update to minimum iOS 4.3 because of xCode 4.5...

Comment: @Mausimo I'm with Justin: Using iOS 4.3+, you don't support additional device models; you only gain access to a small, pre-iOS-5 user-base (some fraction of the [pre-iOS 5 users listed here](http://chitika.com/ios-version-distribution), as those numbers presumably include armv6), a target group reticent/negligent to upgrade their iOS. So you gain something like a 2-3% market opportunity, a trailing-edge technology audience, and lose out on iOS 5 features and/or increase complexity with add'l runtime version checking logic. The calculus will differ for everyone, but 4.3 isn't worth it for me.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the insight. I definitely can see both your points and arguments. For now I will stick with iOS 4.3 because the app I have works with a specific piece of hardware that is only sold to a few thousand users per year. Making this as compatible as possible for those users is very important (also, I have a version with a bunch of updates ready to go for iOS 4.3). I will definitely revisit the idea of updating to iOS 5+ in the near future. Cheers.

Comment: +1 on the iPad 1st gen, forgot all about it. But, it's stuck on iOS 5.something. Third party hardware compatibility is a big must.